# Un-archiving single file hanging

Tags: linux, tar

I am trying to unarchive a very large directory. Here is what works to untar the entire thing:

```
$ sudo tar -xjf itunes20140618.tbz --verbose
x itunes20140618/
x itunes20140618/genre_artist
x itunes20140618/imix_type
...etc...
```

However, if I try and un-archive only a single file, it will correctly do so, but then the command will hang indefinitely. In addition, it doesn't print any of the output when using the --verbose statement. Here is an example:

```
$ sudo tar -xjf itunes20140618.tbz itunes20140618/imix --verbose
[ nothing prints...it just hangs. But it does un-tar that single file ]
```

Comment: @Ramesh Uh? No. This other thread doesn't have any bearing on the present question. Its title is vaguely related but looking at the question body shows that the problem was a different one (absolute paths).

Answer (score 1):

Don't specify  options after non-option arguments,  especially  with `tar` which is a non-standard command with several implementations supporting several ancient and newer ways to parse options, actions and arguments to those.

In:

```
tar -xjf itunes20140618.tbz itunes20140618/imix --verbose
```

`itunes20140618.tbz` would be an argument for the `-f` option, `itunes20140618/imix` an extra non-option argument taken as the name of a member to extract from the archive. Whether `--verbose` will be treated as an extra argument (the name of another member to extract) or an option will depend on the implementation and version of `tar` and even possibly how it was compiled or the runtime environment.

In your case, it may very well be that your `tar` is one of those (the majority) that doesn't take that `--verbose` as a global option.

Here, use:

```
tar -xjf itunes20140618.tbz --verbose itunes20140618/imix
```

Or the more portable:

```
bunzip2 < itunes20140618.tbz | tar xvf - itunes20140618/imix
```

Or replace `tar` with the standard (though less portable) `pax`:

```
bunzip2 < itunes20140618.tbz | pax -vr itunes20140618/imix
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using `bzip2` which is not a [file archiver](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_archiver) so `tar` essentially acts as a  `file archiver` and `bzip2` compresses them.

For example, archiving a collection of files with tar and then compressing the resulting archive file with gzip results a file with .tar.gz extension.

But this approach has a disadvantage as stated in wiki article:

Extracting or modifying one file is difficult. Extracting one file requires decompressing an entire archive, which can be time- and space-consuming.

So my suggestion is go with only `.tar` or `.zip` or `.rar` if you frequently extract a single file.

Comment: What is the best way to unarchive a `tbz` file then? Is there an alternative to tar, which is faster to unarchive a single file?

Comment: I feel `zip` is good as `zip` format has central directory of all files contained in it with direct offsets pointing to the middle of the zip file, so archive members can be quickly extracted without processing whole thing.

Comment: No, I'm not compressing the file. I'm download the file and then I need to unarchive it. I don't have control of how the file currently is. Given that it is a tbz file, how would I decompress a single file in it?

Comment: you have to process the whole `tbz` file and I feel nothing can be done for it.

Comment: Technically it only has to decompress the file until it reaches the one you are trying to extract.  After that, it can stop.  This is also true with uncompressed tar: it still has to read the whole file until it reaches the one you want to extract.  It just doesn't have to spend CPU time decompressing the file as well, which may take more, or less time than reading the uncompressed data.